# Android | How to add an integer in SharedPreferences and prevent it from returning to zero

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I want to add an integer and store it to SharedPreferences. First, I instantiate it to zero then, when the button is clicked, I want to add 1 to it and save it on SharedPreferences. However, it goes back to zero when the activity is recreated due to the instantiating step. How should I do it?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The bad thing is, due to desperation, I deleted that part of my code. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to init zero, try global the variable

```
int value;
```

and like this in onCreate

```
value=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("value", 0);
```

and like this on button click

```
value++;
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("value", value).commit();
```

Comment: I'll try this. Will tell you if it was successful.

Comment: Wait, before I try. This will set the integer named value to zero onCreate. Then, when clicked, it will add 1 to the value and put it in the 'value' key. And on start again, it will be set again to zero, am I right?

Comment: Oh, I get it. The "rezero-ing" will not be saved in SharedPreferences! It will just set value to zero. But the last inserted value remains to be incremented. Right?

Comment: But, how will I be able to get the value of the inputted value from SharedPreferences BEFORE I INCREMENT?

Answer (score 0):

you can write some class like below.. i have just write it, dont know it will work or not but you'll get some idea..

```
 public class Value {
        public static final String KEY_VALUE_ID = "value";
        private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
        private Editor prefsEditor;

        public Value(Context context) {
            this.sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("APP", 0);
            this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        }

        public int getValue(){
            return sharedPrefs.getInt(KEY_VALUE_ID, 0);
        }

        public void setValue(){
            prefsEditor.putInt( KEY_VALUE_ID, getValue() + 1 );
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }    

    }
```

and how to use it in ur class:

on button click call this method:

```
new Value(this).setValue();
```